# C++ Displaying char inside a 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to display the char `Ninja`but for some reason when my array loads up, the map is empty inside. I have the char Ninja defined before the map is cleared so I'm not sure what could be wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //characters

    //nina character coordinates
    char Ninja = 'N';
    int NinjaX = 20;
    int NinjaY = 50;

    char Samurai = 'S';
    char Horsemen = 'H';
    char Spearmen = 'M';
    char Archer = 'A';

    //map size
    const int H = 35;
    const int W = 82;
    char Map[H][W];

    int GameOver = 0;

    //display ninja character
    Map[NinjaX][NinjaY] = Ninja;


    //display map
    for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ )  // display the map
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < W; j++)
        {
            if(i == 0 || i == 34 || j == 0 || j == 81)
                Map[i][j] = 'x';
            else Map[i][j] = ' ';
            cout << Map[i][j];

        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and it will help you.

Comment: You are over-writing the stored value with a space.

Comment: how can I display the value while clearing everything else?

Comment: not good, i need to display it using NinjaX and NinjaY because I will be manipulating those to make the char move around the map

Comment: ok, so use them! else if(i=NinjaX && j=NinjaY) continue;

Comment: Can you show me an example to accept as an answer?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, you know, when you are tired

Comment: Why does your section titled "display the map" actually change every cell in the map? Your display function should just display what's there, and you should make changes to the map in another part of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I applaud you urge to reduce redundancy by using only one loop I must insist that you loop the map twice. First you initialize it with border and blanks. Then, after the initialization and outside any loop, you put everything on it (archers, ninjas etc.). And then you iterate over the map again in order to print it, with everything that's on it.

Currently you are initializing **after** you put stuff on the map, which overwrites it, as others have pointed out.

Comment: Haha I really was trying to do everything within one loop but now I see that its some what impossible lol

Answer (score 0):

user1990169 is correct.  You are over writing values in Map before you display them.  It seems to me that you are trying to initialize your game board (Map) with a border in the same loop that you display it.  The simplest and most flexible solution is to initialize the blank map first and then place your Ninja.  Then loop through again to display the Map later.  If you really have to do it all in one loop, it can be done:

```
//display map
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ )  // display the map
{
    for(int j = 0; j < W; j++)
    {
        if (Map[i][j] == Ninja)
          cout << Map[i][j];
        else
        {
           if(i == 0 || i == 34 || j == 0 || j == 81)
             Map[i][j] = 'x';
           else Map[i][j] = ' ';
           cout << Map[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You probably want to compare, not assign Ninja in the if clause.

Comment: Yes.  Typing on my phone.  Fixed it.  Thanks.